# Rails 3 Select(dropdown menu) Verification

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, validation

I am new to rails and am making a simple form. In the form I have a field that asks "Do you like ice cream?"

```
<%= f.label "Do you like ice cream?" %>
<%= f.select :support_type, [['Yes'],['No']] %>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
```

I would like to validate that the user chose "Yes" and spit out an error and highlight the form (like validates_presence_of would do for an incomplete form) if the user submits the "No" answer. I created a validate method:

```
  def validate
  if self.support_type == 'Yes'
    errors.add(:support_type, "You are crazy")
    return false
  end
  end
```

but this didn't seem to work for me. Any help or hints would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your model do the following:

```
validate :my_validation_method

def my_validation_method
  if self.support_type == 'Yes'
    errors.add(:support_type, "You are crazy")
    return false
  end
end
```

Validate is a class method which needs to be given a validator method name.

You can have several of them:

```
validate :my_validation_method
validate :my_validation_method2
```